# Django - Extending Global Static HTML Template

Tags: django, django-templates

**Description**

How could I extend `base.html` in my apps using following folder structure

**Folder Structure**

```
└───project
    ├───plots # <-- app
    ├───project 
    ├───projects # <-- app
    ├───static # <-- project static files
    │   ├───css
    │   ├───html
    │   └───img
    └───users # <-- app
```

**Settings File**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

and I do use `static` files via `{% load static %}` - `{% static '/css/base.css' %}`

I also know how to use `{% extends file %}` - `{% extends users/html/base.html %}`

I would like to `extend` from `static` folder like such `{% extends 'html/base.html' %}`, however I can't find a way how to achieve this relation.

**Alternative Solution**

I found an alternative way to get it to work modifying `templates` entry in projects settings file. It works but, if possible, I would like to keep all static files in one place.

**Folder Structure**

```
└───project
    ├───plots # <-- app
    ├───project 
    ├───projects # <-- app
    ├───static # <-- project static files
    │   ├───css
    │   └───img
    ├───templates #<-- !now `base.html` is here!
    └───users # <-- app
```

**Settings**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: The template loader looks for your templates in the directories listed in `DIRS`. So, you can put the path to the `static` directory here and it should work. Although, the general django convention is to keep all your html templates in a directory called `templates`. Suppose in future, you collaborate with other django developers, this will lead to confusion.

Comment: I see, so would you suggest I should keep my `html` files in a folder `templates` instead? Is there some `default` loader that looks specifically for this `folder` to be present when loading templates? ( I am fairly a beginner in Django ) working on my first project.

Comment: I would suggest you start with default config so templates folder, inside of that folder you can organize your HTML in subfolders as you wish. Also as this is your first project you could check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#configuration) settings you have

> DIRS defines a list of directories where the engine should look for template source files, in search order.

```
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
    ],
```

If you want your template engine to see other folders or replace current, just add them up

Also, there is a big difference between templates and static files

Comment: So, would I just do something like `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/html')` in my `TEMPLATES` declaration?

Comment: Yes, but static files and templates in the same category doesn't make a lot of sense to me :)

Comment: Static files you can think about as assets, which can be served from CDN, but templates are something your templating engine requires to parse out

Comment: Ah, I see. In my mind I saw `html` files as part of static file pool hence the question. It didn't seem like it was the "Django way", so appreciate what you are saying.